# Data synchronization algorithm/rules for android devices connected as client-server

Tags: android, data-synchronization

My project has multiple android devices connected to each other via bluetooth. One android device acts as a server and rest of them as clients. Each client sends a message to the server and the server forwards the message to rest of the connected clients.

Now I want to synchronize a data list among all the connected devices. Since there is already a channel open between the devices, I would like to use it to send synchronization events/data so that all the devices are in sync. The sync data list will mostly have the list of devices connected, their status, the list of events which they are interested.

Initially, when all the devices are connected, the server can request for client data from every connected devices and then send the overall data list. This way initially all the devices will be in sync.

Below are the questions which I am not sure of when there is a change to data:

1. How do I make sure that there is no conflict or loss of data when more than one client devices make changes?
2. Which is the best way in this case - send only the delta or the whole data?

Is there any algorithm or protocol which I can refer? How should I build the algorithm for data synchronization in this case?